# laptop keeps working while it shows that "1 minute battary remaining"

Tags: laptop, battery

When my lenovo laptops shows that battery is almost finished (1 minute remaining) it keep working.

I was watching HD movie for 20 minutes after that and laptop still showed that "1 minute remaining".

Obviously there is problem with "calculating remaining time".

How to fix this problem? Should I discharge battery completely? Should I use "Battery gauge reset"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Lenovo forums, it would appear that you need to "recondition" the battery.  This basically resets the battery, or rather the percentage of charge left indicator.

> Start up Power Manager. Select the 'BATTERY'  tab. Then select the 'Battery Maintenance...' tab.  At this point select the 'Perform Reset...' tab.

Or... from another site regarding Lenovo laptops and battery "reconditioning"...

> Search your laptop's Control Panel or Start Menu for the Power Management software.  To recondition your battery on Lenovo laptops, click on the "Battery Maintenance" button on the Battery Information tab of the Power Manager. Before proceeding, make sure your laptop can be left unused and plugged into AC power for 4-5 hours.  Then click on the "Perform Reset" button. You will be notified when the recondition is complete.

So, in other words... Yes.  You should use "battery gauge reset".

Of course, knowing how old the laptop is, and how old the battery is might make a difference... like between recommending reconditioning or getting a new battery.

Comment: laptop is 18 month old. battery cycle count is only ~60 and battery about 80% from it's original size (according to lenovo tool report). can `battery gauge reset` make my battery worst? is it dangerous to use battery with it's current condition? basicly i don't care about "indicator" but i'm afraid that wrong indicator affects battery life as battery probably charged or used in a wrong way?

Comment: @javapowered no, using the reset tool won't harm your battery.  No, it's not dangerous to use the battery in it's current condition.  I don't necessarily recommend that you get another battery either.  Using the reset function should return the % charge back to where it should be.